# FusionPBX Ring Group Set Out Bound Caller ID

Tags: fusionpbx

I have a working inbound DID thats routed to a Ring Group that has 3 external cell numbers assigned to it. When a call comes in and hits the Ring group it is successfully routed out to the 3 external numbers, however, it passes along the original callers caller id and not the caller id for the Outbound route. Does anyone know how to have fusionpbx use the caller id for the outbound route?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a single outbound call it uses the outbound route. When you are using a ring group the destinations are used with the bridge statement. The only way to send the call through the outbound route is to use loopback.

Ring Group Destination to an external number.

loopback/2081231234